# Is there a way to find the name of the current theme in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, themes

I have setup theme in Chrome, but it was awhile ago, probably when Chrome got official support for themes. 
I can't find the way to get the name of my current theme installed. I want to use same theme on other machines, but don't know which one is it.

So, how to get name of currently installed theme in Google Chrome?

Comment: maybe you can add a screenshot, there are only 34 themes :)

Comment: I have found which theme it is from chrome theme list. But the question remains, how to find in Chrome what is current theme?

Comment: There are far more than 34 themes: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/themes?hl=en

Comment: A Chrome update has made all the complex and OS specific answers unnecessary. See https://superuser.com/a/1441776/3376

Answer (score 16):

The easiest way to find the name of your theme for Chrome is;
Click on the menu button then select Settings
Click on Get Themes
In the upper right corner you will see your email address followed by a cog icon. Click on the cog.
Select Your Apps
A list of all your apps will be displayed including your theme(s)

Comment: This is waay easiest method!

Answer (score 15):

Open file: `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences`

NOTE: Path will vary from OS to OS... I am using Windows 7. Above file has no extension

Goto:

```
    "settings": (NOTE: it's inside "extensions" section){
    "[ExtensionOrApplicationId]":{

    }

....
}
```

Above section lists all the extensions installed on your machine for the current user.

Now search for section "theme". In this section values againt the sections `"id":<ExtensionOrApplicationId>` and `pack` points to the current theme. In general this section looks as below

```
  "theme": {
     "id": "ddgmdidminnkiajaonminefjlllglgap",
     "pack": "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Extensions\\ddgmdidminnkiajaonminefjlllglgap\\1.0_0\\Cached Theme.pak"
  }
```

If you will simply replace value `ddgmdidminnkiajaonminefjlllglgap` with some other theme id and restart Chrome then the new theme will get loaded.

Hope it helps... ;-)

Answer (score 6):

**chrome://settings/**

Type this on your address bar and click enter. You get the name of your current theme under the 'Appearance' section

[image: Appearance screenshot]

Comment: This is a new feature added to Chrome and is now THE answer.

Comment: For me under Appearance it just says "Open Chrome Web Store".
Version 88.0.4324.104 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 4):

I had i the same problem as you and found a way. An very ugly way, so if you have a lot of extensions installed this could be some work:

1. Find the folder where the chrome extensions are placed. On Windows XP this is: `C:\Documents and Settings\"USER NAME"\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions`
2. Here is a lot of folders with weird names. I guess they are unique identifiers for every extension. I then used an url from the new Google Chrome Web Store like this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oeljdmeofcikjblcoehpmdnooimalbmj)
   and changed the last part of the url with the ones from the folders. One of them was my theme and the page showed the name.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem as you, and I solved it by noticing, that when I click on an extension in Chrome Web Store, then the same ID appears in the address bar, as the one in the extensions folder!

So you can simply replace that in the URL, and it will take you to the proper extension/theme.

Example:

- URL: `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pgbdhkpacgdhfabeceekiafonfkipohm?hl=en`
- Path: `[Windows7Partition]:\Users\[CurrentUser]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\pgbdhkpacgdhfabeceekiafonfkipohm`

in this example the id was `pgbdhkpacgdhfabeceekiafonfkipohm`

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to find out the current theme via the [chrome.management](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html) API.
You need to run this from an extension which has the [management permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html) in its manifest.

**CODE, e.g. run in JS Console**

```
chrome.management.getAll(function (extensionInfoArray) {
    extensionInfoArray.forEach(function (extensionInfo) {
        if (extensionInfo.type === "theme" && extensionInfo.enabled) {
            console.log(extensionInfo);
        }});
})
```

**OUTPUT in JS Console**

```
Object {
description: "",
enabled: true,
homepageUrl: "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hnfhcmjkebafbfikmbkhdpbmfpfjgiog",
hostPermissions: Array[0], id: "hnfhcmjkebafbfikmbkhdpbmfpfjgiog"…}
description: ""
enabled: true
homepageUrl: "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hnfhcmjkebafbfikmbkhdpbmfpfjgiog"
hostPermissions: Array[0]
id: "hnfhcmjkebafbfikmbkhdpbmfpfjgiog"
installType: "normal"
isApp: false
mayDisable: true
name: "Minimal"
offlineEnabled: false
optionsUrl: ""
permissions: Array[0]
type: "theme"
updateUrl: "http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"
version: "1.0"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: The easiest way to do this is go to main menu > Extensions, and then hit F12 to open devtools.  You can run the code above in the console for that page.

Answer (score 3):

Go into the Chrome Store and install "[***Extensions Manager(aka Switcher)***](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extensions-manager-aka-sw/lpleipinonnoibneeejgjnoeekmbopbc?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)"

This utility will tell you not only which THEME you have installed, but will allow you to have multiple themes which you can switch between, as desired.

[image: Themes]

In addition, the "Extensions Manager(aka Switcher)" also shows all EXTENSIONS & APPLICATIONS you currently have installed and which ones are active and which are turned off.

[image]

You can also ACTIVATE, DEACTIVATE or UNINSTALL your Extensions and/or Applications from within this manager.

Comment: There is also [SimpleExtManager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simpleextmanager/kniehgiejgnnpgojkdhhjbgbllnfkfdk) with less clutter.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I wasn't sure which of several similarly named themes I was using.  I knew it was one of the Ubuntu-themed ones, though.

I found that Chrome pointed it out with a green check [when I searched on the Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-themes/ubuntu?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon):

[image: Chrome Web Store searching for "ubuntu" themes with chosen theme having green check in top left corner]

This might not help in all circumstances, but it got me the information I needed to share [my current theme](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ubuntu-black-magic-theme/nnckfbibnhikbljjnipfknnmjpafdbla?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) with someone.

Answer (score 1):

There is very easy way to find the name of the current chrome theme.Open folder 
"C:\Documents and Settings\"USER NAME"\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions". There are folders which each one represents extension you have installed.Browse them and in theme one it is another folder with name like this 1.0_0. And in this final folder is file "manifest.json". So open it with notepad and you will see the required name.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Chrome.
2. If you have a page open on startup, click the New Tab button.
3. Click on "Customize" in the bottom right corner.
4. Select "colour and theme".

Here you can find your currently active theme name by hovering over the selected theme.

Answer (score 0):

Another helpful tip, after identifying the theme via the accepted answer, if you search the Chrome Store for the theme and cannot set it because you get the message: "Added to Chrome", you should go to Chrome Settings and set the Default theme, restart the browser and then search the store for the theme you wanted (previously identified) and you should be able to add it.

Answer (score 0):

With Windows Explorer, go to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome` and search for `.pak`.  For example, mine finds `Cached Theme.pak`.

Right click and choose Open File Location.  The resulting path will tell you the name of the theme, e.g. `...\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\gapfoeoijjkibljnhednndeabimdilek\2_0`.

Use this name to find the right page in the store: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/classic-blue-theme/gapfoeoijjkibljnhednndeabimdilek?hl=en-GB&gl=US